# JS library for creating a mindmap like interface

Tags: javascript

I have to create an interface similar to what http://www.madeiracloud.com provides for drawing a network architecture (for different purposes than what they are doing).

Basically users should be able to drag & drop elements to a canvas and connect them using directional arrows.

What library should I use for this? I'm looking at d3, raphael and ocanvas.

Comment: Ive used this one [js-mindmap](http://www.liamsullivan.co.uk/fyp/mindmap/). You can also have a try.

Comment: [mapjs](https://github.com/mindmup/mapjs)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Raphaël ( http://raphaeljs.com/ )in combination with the Dracula Graph Library( http://dracula.ameisenbar.de/ ) will get you started.

and also thejit is perfect:

Multi-Trees
The JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit provides tools for creating Interactive Data Visualizations for the Web.

http://thejit.org/

**Edit:**

you can also take a look at Processing.js

http://processingjs.org/

Processing.js is the sister project of the popular Processing visual programming language, designed for the web. Processing.js makes your data visualizations, digital art, interactive animations, educational graphs, video games, etc. work using web standards and without any plug-ins. You write code using the Processing language, include it in your web page, and Processing.js does the rest.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at the [MindMap](https://github.com/kennethkufluk/js-mindmap) project which use [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) internally.

You can find the demo at http://kenneth.kufluk.com/google/js-mindmap/

[image]

Comment: I know this is old but I have been using kufluk's mind-map for awhile, want to make it work on mobile jQuery? any thoughts if that's possible?

Answer (score 1):

In a commercial context you should also take a look at what [yFiles for HTML](http://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) has to offer.

It's a generic graph drawing and editing javascript library which solves your "drag and drop and connect" use-case easily. There is also a specific [mind map example](http://live.yworks.com/demobrowser/#Mindmaps) available online:

[image: Mind map Demo application screenshot]

but in this application nodes are not created via drag and drop. This however of course is possible, too, as can be seen in [this online demo](http://live.yworks.com/demobrowser/#Business-Process-Models).

The specific strengths of that library are automatic layout/arrangement of nodes and connections, so if you are creating larger networks or populating the graph automatically from an external data-source these come in very handy. However if you don't require this feature set, simpler solutions may work, too, of course. Note that d3 has the focus on *viewing* data, and is not so much about user interaction and creating graphs interactively.

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for the company that creates that library, however I do not represent my employer on SO. My comments are my own.</sup>